# What searching algorithm does Dynamodb use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, uuid

The reason for this question is:

We are planning to have a UUID as a partition key for an id of a user, company, and load tables for a load board project and we are using DynamoDB.

The thing is when we have thousands of records in a DynamoDB supposedly a user table and I want to search a user with their user-id.

Will the search be more efficient with UUID(ff44393c-bec6-4005-a966-15050fd9bb77) or normal Interger id like (001,002.....)?as partition key.

I could also see that UUID format is a standard which is maintained by most of the application but not sure if their use cases match ours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is AWS blog which gives recommendations regarding the partition key:

- [Choosing the Right DynamoDB Partition Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)

One of the recommendations given is:

> **Use high-cardinality attributes**. These are attributes that have distinct values for each item, like e-mailid, employee_no, customerid, sessionid, orderid, and so on.

What's more they write that **using sequences** is an anti-pattern. Thus, it think `UUID` would be better in your case.

Comment: the concern is with the reading of data. 
Having a non-uniform auto-generated UUID be help in this?

Comment: @sumanthshetty As the blog writes, there is no solution to fit all possible cases. You can read the blog, do some tests and evaluate pros and cons of both possibilities.

Comment: can we have multiple columns for a partition key? like 
customerid+productid+countrycode be a partition on its own? if so how?

Comment: @sumanthshetty Yes, you would just concatenate the three strings into one, joined primary key.

Comment: oh okay, I suppose a similar thing goes to sort key as well if in case we want multiple sort key ?

Comment: Could you help me out with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64985504/returning-only-the-subset-for-response-from-dynamdb-scan